# VB - Fill cell background based on date comparing today to cell value

Tags: vba, reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a column that returns dates in this form:

> "2016-06-01 23:29:34.283"

I am wondering how I can fill the cell background green if the day matches today, and red if its not today (hour and minute doesn't matter).

I tried this but no luck:

```
=Switch(Fields!Last_Upload.value = Today(), "Green", Fields!Last_Upload.value != Today(), "Red").
```

Edit: This is using VS Data Tools

Comment: Is it in excel ? if yes then this can be done by conditional formatting.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to achieve this. Select the column, Home->ConditionalFormatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> A Date Occurring

Comment: @newguy using VS - Data Tools!

Answer (score 2):

Of course the problem is comparing the date without the timestamp. You can use the `DateValue` function for this like so:

```
=IIf(DateValue(Fields!Last_Upload.value) = Today, "Green", "Red")
```